# Creating Clonezilla image on large drive and putting it onto smaller drive

Tags: clonezilla

I am creating a Windows 7 Clonezilla image and while I have used the product before I am unable to find any documtation that will tell me if:

If I create a Clonezilla image on a 500 GB standard hard drive, will it work if I attempt to put it onto a 111 GB SSD?

Do I need to only create a 111 GB SSD?
All the other hardware is identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i've found to my cost (and doumented on the CloneZilla site):

> Limitations: The destination
>   partition must be equal or larger than
>   the source one.

You could use GParted or a Linux Live CD to "shrink" the partition to 100GB, then image that. You will then be able to restore the sub-110GB image to the disk.